# Difference between SQL Server and SQLite 'LIKE' function

Tags: sql-server, sqlite

I am working with two databases, one is MS SQL Server, the other is SQLite. Both contain identical data which I can and have verified (at least, they are as identical as the different languages will allow). In working with the two, I came across a confusing difference in the way the two languages perform:

When I run the following query in SQL Server:

```
SELECT
    count(*)
FROM
    Pattern as p
WHERE
    'RK69M|1M116849' like replace(p.Keys, '*', '_') + '%'
```

I get:
`47040`

But when I run the equivalent query in SQLite (the only difference is concatenation in SQL Server is `+` but SQLite uses `||`):

```
SELECT 
count(*)
FROM
    Pattern as p
WHERE
    'RK69M|1M116849' like replace(p.Keys, '*', '_') || '%'
```

I get: `43197`

Can anyone explain this? Do they use different regex's for matching?

If it matters, in both, the count of records in the the table (removing the `where` clauses) is `1304884`

I have also tried running the query through multiple channels (TSQL, python, GUI-based query tools, etc), and all get the same result.
I've also tested the data with both a python script to compare them and by dumping them to a text file and using the diff command in linux, so I am confident it is the same data in each database.

Comment: This has nothing to do with LIKE, it's just that different languages use different operators to concatenate strings. If you're trying to write code that can't take account of these differences, then you'll have to concatenate outside and pass it into the query as a strongly typed parameter (which is the safer way to do it anyway).\

Comment: I'd just export results from both queries to text files and diff them to see what are the differences to find the problem.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I don't think the problem is with the concatenation. maybe I focused too much on that in the post, but I have tested and `||` performs the same operation as `+`. What I am wondering is why the number of results is different with the same patterns.

Comment: Right, I was only mentioning it in case the goal was to write a single query that works in both. As others have mentioned, the * is a problem too. For the problem of different number of rows, like the others, find out _which_ rows are different, which will help you understand _why_. We couldn’t possibly guess why counts are different. Finally, as for performance, I sure hope you don’t ever expect this to perform well, especially as the tables grow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [In SQL Server] I get: 47040
> [In Sqlite] I get: 43197
> Can anyone explain this? Do they use different regex's for matching?

It's not regex at all. `LIKE` is its own thing. But as is often the case with this kind of question, we can gain insight by going to the documentation.

[Here is SQL Server's LIKE operator documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

The relevant portion from SQL Server describes four different tokens for pattern matching: `%`, `_`, `[]`, and `[^ ]`

[Here is Sqlite's documentation](https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html)
*(scroll down to section 5)*

The relevant portion only describes the first two pattern tokens: `%` and `_`.

The documentation for both databases includes additional information on things like escape characters and such that are not used in your query, except the Sqlite documentation includes this:

> The LIKE operator is case sensitive by default for unicode characters that are beyond the ASCII range.

I don't know the nature of your data or whether that will matter here, but I can say SQL Server's handling of the same issue depends on the collation, and therefore isn't necessarily the same.

---

The point is there are documented differences in how the two database engines behave in this area, and therefore given significant data you should expect somewhat different results.